# Intellij 14 GDSL

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, dsl, intellij-14

Anyone have any luck with IntelliJ 14.0.2 and Groovy DSL (GDSL) descriptors?

We modeled our GDSL around the instructions [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness) and [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/use-groovydsl-in-intellij-idea.html) for IntelliJ 13 it worked like a charm. Upgraded to 14 and Groovy code completion no longer works. Documentation around this feature is pretty rough so we're kind of out of ideas.

Here's our current GDSL which allowed code completion in scripts like `thing.POST.groovy`:

```
def all = context(pathRegexp: '/.*\\.[A-Z]+\\.groovy', scope: scriptScope())

contributor(all) {
  property name: 'response', type: 'com.foo.HttpResponse'
  property name: 'request', type: 'com.foo.HttpRequest'
}
```

This lives in `src/test/groovy/expectationTransform.gdsl`. IntelliJ prompts to "Activate Back" but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: If this is an IDE bug (and it sounds like it is), your best bet would be to submit a ticket to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/ if you haven't already and hope it gets fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks @kuporific - I've started with the message board and will see where it goes from there... https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/459033

Comment: Decided to just create this issue as well: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134339

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the Groovy plugin. See [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134339) for details.

He said the fix will be pushed as an update to the Groovy plugin.